# What should my program do when it sees an integer overflow that does not affect the program run?

Tags: c, integer-overflow

There is a small program which takes input from users on a prompt. It takes predefined inputs from the users and executes them.

It also displays a number with the prompt indicating the count of the commands :

```
myprompt 1) usercommand1
...
myprompt 2) usercommand2
...
...
myprompt 3)
```

I do not expect the user to give more than 65535 commands at a time, so the `count` is stored as an `unsigned short` data.

**Problem:**

I am not sure how the program should handle the case when the user actually crosses this limit of the number of commands. Should I let the count to roll over to 0 (and keep looping) or to stay put at 65535?

I want the program to still *function normally*, as in take user inputs and process them just as before. Also, the value of count has no effect at all on the command execution.

Comment: if you don't know a type is sufficiently capable of storing a value or may affect your implementation, choose an appropriate type. in this case: `int32_t` may be a better choice. storage size is typically not an issue.

Comment: @Justin, you are right, but that is besides the point. I want to know how to handle the limit (which would be there with `int32_t` as well).

Comment: there is no *practical* limit with a 32 bit int since a user could not enter 2e9 commands in their lifetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looks like you're tackling a problem that might never occur.

Let's assume your users are quite fast, and it takes them 10 seconds to input a command line. Rollover would happen after 655350 seconds, i.e. approximately *seven and a half days*.

Let the counter roll over. If that still troubles you, then take the high path and make it an `unsigned long`. Then it will only roll over after 1361 *years* (on 32-bit machines).

Comment: Note that another program could be feeding commands to Lazer’s program.

Comment: @kmkaplan, true :) But what about counter rollover in *that* program? ;)

Comment: That’s exactly why I suggested Lazer to ask the *user* of his program what the correct behaviour should be. May be it is capable of handling huge integers…

Answer (score 2):

If you ask yourself this question it means you should go the easy way: make the counter an `unsigned int`.

How to handle the limit is very dependant on what this counter is used for. My feeling is that it is not used for any really interesting thing so your question is kind of moot. Whichever choice you make it will still work correctly.

On the other hand if this counter as some *real* use you should ask the user of this counter the correct way to proceed: both have some pros and cons (either counter going back in time or stalling) so your user risk being surprised.

You forgot to mention other alternatives: terminate your program. Or remove the limit and use some form of big integers (GMP lib for example) but this souns overkill.

Note that the DNS choose to wraparound the serial number at 2^32. This makes it usable forever. Users of the counter are supposed to detect the overflow. [RFC 1982](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1982)

Comment: No.. that is not the point. A limit is still there. How to handle the limit?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest this:

> I want the program to still function
>   normally, as in take user inputs and
>   process them just as before. Also, the
>   value of count has no effect at all on
>   the command execution.

answers your own question, if it has no effect at all then just let it start on 0 again.